# Flash CC AS3 - using .swc files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swc

I am so fed up with not being able to figure out how to use .swc files. I have searched and searched but everywhere I go, people only explain the step of linking the `.swc` file in your publish `settings > library path> SWC` etc.

The problem is, I don't understand what to do after that. linking it seems to do nothing. I'm sure I am probably missing something obvious.

I am following the steps on [this page](http://api.shephertz.com/tutorial/Getting-Started-Action-Script/?index=gs-as3sdk&sdk=flash#initialize_sdk) EXACTLY.

but after importing and trying to initialize the `.swc` with the code given, my compiler throws this error:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1, Column 33    1180: Call to a possibly undefined method ServiceAPI.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1, Column 16    1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ServiceAPI.
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to import these classes? I believe that is the reason. Try:

```
  import com.shephertz.app42.paas.sdk.as3.user.UserService;
  import com.shephertz.app42.paas.sdk.as3.ServiceAPI;
  import com.shephertz.app42.paas.sdk.as3.storage.StorageService;

  var serviceAPI:ServiceAPI = new ServiceAPI('apiKey', 'secretKey');
  var userService:UserService = serviceAPI.buildUserService();  
  var storageService:StorageService = serviceAPI.buildStorageService();
```

Comment: Adding the swc just makes those classes avaiable to be used by the program. But they will not be used if you have no reference to them. When you want to use them in your class you must also import them.